# Allow a user to move a borderless window

Tags: vb.net

I have a form without borders that I would like the user to be able to move. I have not been able to find anything that would allow me to do so.

Is it possible to move a window with the border set to None?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Introduce a Boolean variable which holds the state if the form is currently dragged and variables which hold the starting point of the drag. Then OnMove move the form accordingly. As this has already been answered elsewhere, I just copy&paste it here.

```
Class Form1
    Private IsFormBeingDragged As Boolean = False
    Private MouseDownX As Integer
    Private MouseDownY As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            IsFormBeingDragged = True
            MouseDownX = e.X
            MouseDownY = e.Y
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            IsFormBeingDragged = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove

        If IsFormBeingDragged Then
            Dim temp As Point = New Point()

            temp.X = Me.Location.X + (e.X - MouseDownX)
            temp.Y = Me.Location.Y + (e.Y - MouseDownY)
            Me.Location = temp
            temp = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

stolen from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59643-moving-form-with-formborderstyle-none/

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

All 'simple' VB answers made my form jump all over the place with multiple screens. So i derived this from same answer in C# and it works like a charm :

```
Public Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = 161
Public Const HT_CAPTION As Integer = 2
```

then

```
 <DllImport("User32")> Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer

End Function

<DllImport("User32")> Private Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean

End Function
```

and finally

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
        ReleaseCapture()
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This needs up voting more unless someone has a reason why it's bad.  I have been trying the other methods including my own and they are all laggy and on complex forms or slow PCs tend to leave the form behind.  This is clean and fast.  Well done.  It is worth adding that you need to modify the handles to the control(s) that are responsible for the drag.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` [message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . This allows you to have parts of your form respond to mouse events as the title bar, borders, etc. would for a window with borders. For example, if you have a label on your form and you return `HTCAPTION` in the `WM_NCHITTEST` handler, you will be able to move the form by dragging this label just as you can move a regular window by dragging on its title bar. See this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803453/wm-nchittest-htcaption-and-maximized-window) for example code.